# How to find and replace a list item by text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Following is my HTML:**

```
<ul>
  <li>Fruits
    <ul>
      <li>Apple</li>
      <li>Mango</li>
      <li>Banana</li>
      <li>Orange</li>
      <li>Guava</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Cars</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Bikes</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Cities
    <ul>
      <li>Lucknow</li>
      <li>Kanpur</li>
      <li>Varanasi</li>
      <li>Delhi</li>
      <li>Ghaziabad</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Countries</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Celebrities</li>
</ul>
```

I want to replace the list-item "Banana" with "Watermelon". I have written the following jQuery code and its working fine:

```
$("li").slice(3, -12).text("Watermelon");
```

But, to count the index number and pass it in `slice()`, I suppose, is not the right way. So I want to search via text "Banana" and replace it with text "Watermelon".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
$("li").filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == "Banana"; }).replaceWith( "<li>Watermelon</li>");
```

I believe you want to do more than just replacing the string.

jQuery's **replaceWith** replaces the matched element with totally new element.

Comment: Required reading: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire (do not feed.)

Comment: Instead of replacing the entire element, you may just set its `text` to `Watermelon`.

Comment: the code just provided by someone (now deleted his own post) is working fine:   $("li+li:contains('Banana')").text("watermelon");

Comment: Good one. short and simple.@Maverick

Comment: Thanks @melvin I usually avoid using contains, since that is really unsafe to check for contains property. But seems like that's what author of the question ended up choosing.

Comment: Thanks Maverick, to provide the method replaceWith(). I write it like this and it is working fine:     
       $("li+li:contains('Banana')").replaceWith("<li>Watermelon</li>");

Comment: It's not the text but contains('Banana') I'm actually concerned about.

Answer (score 0):

You could call this function to replace value and pass banana as text_to_search and watermelon as

```
function replace_function(text_to_search,text_to_replace){
    $('ul li').each(function () {
        $(this).text === text_to_search ? $(this).text(text_to_replace) : '';
    });
}
```

Comment: Why would you duplicate the two variables like that...?

Comment: @ChrisGoh sorry . Didn't thought of it. Thanks. Updated